# How to balance this equation?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Here is my problem

$$\ce{2X + 16H^{+} + 10Cl^{-} \rightarrow 2Mn^{2+} + 8H_{2}O + 5Cl2}$$

I want to find the $X$ in this reaction.

According to me

$$Mn_{2}O_{3}$$

Also I see that the values of $Cl_2$ and $H$ are equal. There's $8$ Oxygen in subtitles as well $(8H_{2}O)$.

Regards!

Comment: Mn2O3 does not balance Mn since there are 2 Mn2O3. Also that has 6 O on left and 8 on the right. That doesn't seem quite right....

Comment: The amount of oxygen does not add up with that solution!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking ‘am I right’ with respect to a specific exercise are a bad fit for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these numbers are correct and there is just one compound X missing, it is quite simple:

You have 2 manganese on the right, so you need 2 on the left. 8 oxygen on the right, so 8 left. Because stoichiometry is 2, divide these numbers by 2.

This gives you $\ce{1Mn}$ and $\ce{4O}$, forming $\ce{MnO4}$.

**However**, we are still missing the charge!

If you look carefully, you see that on the right you have $2~\cdot~+2=+4$. On the left, you have $+16 -10=+6$. That is $+2$ too much, so you have to add 2 negative charges. Divide by stoichiometry of your compound $\ce{X}$ and add to what you have already.

So your compound $\ce{X}$ must be $\ce{MnO4-}$. Your equation is:

$$\ce{2MnO4- +16H+ + 10Cl- -> 2Mn^{2+} + 8H2O + 5Cl2}$$

This, however, is usually not the way to solve this kind of question.